# There are 6 men and 4 women in a building. You know that there are exactly 3 married couples. In how many ways you can guess who the couples are?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I tried to solve like this:

Ways to chose 3 womens out of 4 →  `4C3 = 4 Ways`
Ways to chose 3 mens out of 6 →  `6C3 = 20 Ways`

Then possible couples can be `4P1 * 20P1 = 80 Ways`

### But answer is
480

Comment: You can assign partners in 3!=6 ways so it is 4x20x6. If you don’t get it, think like this: all the selected females are seated in a row and selected males assigned to them. There are 6 ways of doing this.

Comment: I think we need to ask for clarification in these modern times: Are we to assume that all married couples are heterosexually composed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

José already pointed out the flaw in your answer.

Choosing $3$ men out of $6$ can be done *without paying attention to order*.

After that $3$ women are chosen out of $4$ but this time *with paying attention to order*.

So the outcome is:$$6C3\times4P3=20\times24=480$$

If you start with choosing the $4$ women first then you get:$$4C3\times6P3=4\times120=480$$

Answer (score 2):

That $80$ that you got is the number of ways of getting $3$ women and $3$  men out of a group of $4$ women and a group of $6$ men. After that, you have to form couples. There are three choices for the first woman, then there are two choices for the second woman, and then only one choice for the third one. So, since $3\times2\times1=6$, the answer is $80\times6=480$.